# How do I multiply 2 32-bit integers to produce a 64-bit integer?

Tags: c, int, 32bit-64bit

How do I take an input of 2 32 bit unsigned integers, multiply them and get the output as a 64 bit integer in C? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm

Comment: @Suma No, it is not a duplicate of that post... read the post you linked.

Comment: Indeed, they're not the same. I've removed the automatic comment to prevent further confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t mul64(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    return (uint64_t)x*(uint64_t)y;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Convert the two integers to 64 bit first, then do a normal multiplication and return the value.

Answer (score 2):

Just convert one of the two integers to `uint64_t`:

```
 uint32_t a, b;
 uint64_t c;
 /* assign to a and b */

 c = (uint64_t) a * b;
```